# Get input field name one by one using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code :

HTML:

```
   <input type="text" name="degree" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="passing_year" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="name_of_institute" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="field_of_study" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="grade" /><br />
```

JS:

```
  var name_of_input = $('.input_fields input').attr('name');
```

How can I get all the input field name one by one ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` to iterate over multiple inputs:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eG7NW/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each()` function from jquery library. It iterates over all the jquery objects and in the set and you can do whatever you want to do with them.

In your case you want to get the name of all input elements then you should try this:

```
$('input').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

It will print names of all the input elements in your page to console.